# How to write a C# method accepting varying input parameters without knowing the parameters prior it is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, query-string

I am trying to write a method in `ASP.NET` `MVC` `C#` doing below

1. The method will be called by using URLs like below however different URLs will have different parameters. 
   For example;

   -- URL 1: `host/myController/myMethod?param1=value1&param2=value2`

   -- URL 2: `host/myController/myMethod?param3=value3&param4=value4&param5=value5`
2. The method will not have to know about the parameters prior to the
   call. The parameters themselves and the number of parameters will vary from call to call and the method will accept any parameters.

I tried to use `params string[] myParamaters` for input in the method but when I call the method via URLs myParameters takes a null value.

How can I define the arguments for a controller method like this?

Comment: why not use a method  that's like `ActionResult MyMethod(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, string param5)` and go based off what you inputs are.  I'd suggest using a data object once you get up to 5 variables though.

Comment: I put 5 parameters here but in reality the number of parameters can be many. It may be more than 30 and I do not know what parameters may be called in the requests. So basically the method will accept anything then resolve the names and the values of the parameters within the method.

Comment: What was wrong with [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246052/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-by-using-urls-varying-in-number-of-parameters) so that you asked it again

Comment: I realized my question was not clear there. Your answer was not wrong but not i was actually looking for something else. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @user3622488 My answer? I would never answer it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to parse the QueryString via `Request.QueryString`.  Something like:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    foreach(string key in Request.QueryString) {
        // Do stuff with Request.QueryString[key]
    }
}
```

This way, you won't need a variable parameter list in the method definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the URL parameters from a dictionary that is returned from [HttpRequest.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead of baking the parameters into the action method's prototype, just grab them within the controller, e.g.

```
ActionResult MyAction() //No params
{
    var params = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
}
```